# MySQL innodb files

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I'm trying to run a old `mysql` installation. but it is not starting and not that much clues in .err files.

But when I removed the following files, its started to working.

> ib_logfile0
>   ib_logfile1

Is any problem occur due to this? like any data loss,etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ib_logfile0** and **ib_logfile1** are [InnoDb redo logs files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-redo-log.html) used to recover data when Innodb engine crashes. These files should not be disturbed, if you are concerning about your data.

Kindly check the mysql error log for any error statement logged while starting the mysql instance or please append last hundred or fifty lines to find out what would be happen.

There might be a possibility that the ***innodb_log_file_size*** variable in mysql configuration could have changed which leads to ib_log file size mismatch. After deleting those files, the Innodb engine created new ib_logfiles and started the instance.

The deletion doesn't affect your data directly, but it might leads to inconsistency, if the last shutdown of mysql instance was not graceful. In case of data exists in your current setup and innodb engine (mysql) crashed previously, then it cannot replay the [redo logs to recover the data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-recovery.html).